# Looking for a story about man who gets unremovable mask after mating with creature and then fights giant serpent

Tags: story-identification

I'm looking for a really weird book or story I read a while back.  There were weird creatures disguised as humans.   A man makes the mistake of having sex with one of the them and ends up having a mask put on his face that he can never take off, and he has to wander around naked for a while.  Then he has to fight a giant serpent.  Or something like that.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is the famously weird novel ***Time Snake and Superclown*** (1976) by Vincent King.

[image: Cover of "Time Snake and Superclown" showing a spaceship in flight in front of two sharp, rocky peaks, the taller of which has a castle-like building on it. A yellow planet or dim star looms large in a red sky behind the peaks and a pair of distant spaceships are silhouetted against it.]

The main character, a "Watcher", is charged with looking after the human race, which are now human in appearance only.  Humanity seems to have been replaced by "wraiths": they are "dead" on the inside but wear a kind of synthetic skin on the outside that makes them appear human.  He mates with one of these wraiths, and she subsequently *permanently transforms his face into a clown face*.  I'm not sure that he has to walk around totally naked, but she does steal his pants — something that he is not aware of immediately.  He wanders around bottomless for a good chunk of the book.

By the end of the novel, he fulfills his destiny, which is to battle the Time Snake.

It's been called [the most demented novel of all time](https://gizmodo.com/the-most-demented-novel-of-all-time-5082454).

Comment: I want to read this now; +1

Comment: Nice! Now I want to read it... I was thinking a bit of Orson Scott Card's *Wyrms*, which only kinda matched.... but is similarly demented.

Comment: Yup, this is it.  Can't wait to read this madness again...

Comment: @Lexible : *Time Snake and Superclown* is wonderfully insane.  Enjoy!

Comment: In other news: sales of Time Snake and Superclown mysteriously skyrocket!

Comment: Further proof that drugs were better in the 70's.